# Converting cutoff_frequency_ratio to Cycles/Pixel in Butterworth Filtering with skimage

Tags: image-processing, fft, butterworth, stereo-vision, image-analysis

I am working on my thesis where I'm employing Butterworth filtering on images using the function butterworth from scikit-image's skimage.filters module. The code/formula I'm referring to is available [**here**](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/2ac3e141e8d2e31aa0ec10afc3a935396b0618fc/skimage/filters/_fft_based.py#L58-L185)

For the sake of academic rigor, I need to specify the filtering frequencies in terms of "cycles per pixel" (c/p), which I'll later convert to "cycles per degree" based on the viewing distance and display size.

The function uses a parameter called cutoff_frequency_ratio, which is a floating-point value between 0 and 0.5. I'm a bit unclear on how to translate this into "cycles per pixel".

My questions are:

How can I convert cutoff_frequency_ratio to "cycles per pixel"?
Is the "cycles per pixel" metric dependent on the dimensions of the image being processed?
I've also come across the term "cycles/image" in some forums. How does this differ from "cycles per pixel"?

Any guidance or references on this would be incredibly helpful for my research. Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I convert cutoff_frequency_ratio to "cycles per pixel"?

They are the same thing. By expressing the cut off in terms of the ratio, the physical units, whether they were samples per seconds (Hertz) or samples per meter, have been removed, and you are left cycles per sample. The samples in this case are pixels.

> Is the "cycles per pixel" metric dependent on the dimensions of the image being processed?

No. It is purely a function of how quickly the content can change from one pixel to the next.

> I've also come across the term "cycles/image" in some forums. How does this differ from "cycles per pixel"?

I have never heard the term "cycles/image" before. It sounds specific to a given application or field.

Comment: Thanks!  I infer from the function's documentation and your response that the maximum value for cutoff_frequency_ratio being 0.5 is tied to the Nyquist criterion, suggesting the highest discernible frequency is half the sampling rate. Would you say that's accurate? 

note: In some vision-related journals, I've encountered the term "cycles/image". But they did not specify what it was specifically.

Comment: Finally, if you don't mind, I would appreciate it if you could confirm:
Given:
d = distance from the image in cm;
h = height of the image in cm;
Is the translation from "cycles per pixel" to "cycles per degree" as follows correct?

degrees of visual angle = 2 * atan( h/2 / d );

pixels/degree = total pixels / degrees of visual angle;

cycles/degree = cycles/pixel * pixels/degree;

any textbook or article recommendations on this topic would also be greatly appreciated...

thank you so much again!

Comment: @AltunE Yes, a value of 0.5 corresponds to one half of a cycle per sample, which is the upper Nyquist limit.

Comment: thank you so much for your time!

Comment: @AltunE To convert from pixels to physical units, just use whatever formula is appropriate. I am not familiar with the formulas you provided, and so I cannot say anything useful about them. As for good books, my first book was Oppenheim and Schafer, which you can find free copies of on the web.